# recognizing text effect on an image for photoshop

Tags: image, image-processing, photoshop

I had my site designed through an designer, I have this image from it, I want to use same kind of image for other navigation menus which I want to add now, my designer is not supplying me with psd`s of it.

[image: http://i42.tinypic.com/2afc4fm.jpg]
 [image]

How can I know what text effects and fonts I should use in photoshop to achieve the same kind of result?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a programming question, though I think I can help you.

- Font-face: Verdana (Regular)
- Font-size: 14/15pt Color: #333333
- Text has a layer style > bevel & emboss > Style: Emboss

  - Size & Soften both 0px
- Text left: bevel direction up
- Text right: bevel direction down

I you play around with the shading angles and highlights you should be able to replicate the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Layer > Layer Style > bevel and emboss

but this can be achieved without an image in browsers that support the text-shadow css property

Something like this

```
text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #B5B5B5;
```

Answer (score 0):

[What the font](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) has satisfied my font recognizing needs so far.

Answer (score 0):

It actually look like the treatment of text is a bit inconsistent. In the image on the left the effect is a raised bevel that is coming toward you and in the right it is a letter-press effect.

The image on the right is a bit more involved from a text treatment standpoint. When in Photoshop, select the text layer and look toward the bottom of your layers menu for 'fx'. Choose 'fx' and a window will popup.

Select gradient overlay and set the gradient using white as your foreground color and black as your background color (it should default to this). Bring the opacity down to about 15%.

Next look at the left hand sidebar to drop shadow and select. Choose overlay instead of normal from the dropdown and change your color to white (by clicking the black swatch next to the drop down). All your angles/direction should be 120 degrees for this. While still in the drop down options set your distance to 2px and your size to 3px.

Lastly, apply an inner shadow. Likely the distance and and size should mirror that of the drop shadow given above.

For the tab background, looks like they are doing two thing. First applying a gradient overlay on the tab and then a slight lighting effect. Actually the lighting effect might be hard to duplicate at this subtlety so do one of two things. Create another layer on top of the tab and create a selection from the existing tab (you have to make sure the first tab layer is rasterized to do this) and fill with white. Then apply the lighting effect and adjust the opacity of the layer to get the desired effect. OR if you are a bit artistic you can use the brush tool with a low fill and opacity weight to essentially spot the tab in the middle with white.

For the image on the right, use the same process to treat the tab just change your fill color or gradient overlay foreground and background colors and for the text use a simple drop shadow with distance 2 or 3px and size 2px.

There is a [good tutorial here](http://line25.com/articles/web-design-trend-showcase-letterpress-text-effect) about letterpress effect (scroll down a bit to see the instruction).

Hope that helps.